# invalid handle exception when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, exception

I have following message while I am in debug mode in Visual studio 2010 `Unhandled exception at 0x76c5f9e2 in test.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.`When I run this in regular mode I don't get this error.
The debugger stops in close.c at this line

```
CloseHandle( (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fh) ) )
```

Does anyone have any sugestion how such error could be avoided?

Comment: Why are you doing this anyway? The CRT closes the handle when you call `_close()`. If you close it too, then the handle gets double-closed, and thus you have your `invalid handle` error.

Comment: but why this error happen only when I in debug mode?

Comment: This is one of the cases where the operating system changes its behavior depending on whether you are debugging or not.

Comment: @RaymondChen et al: do you happen to know if there is a way to disable this additional error checking when debugging? I'm using a crappy library which I can't easily modify or rebuild, which gives me the same error (but still "works" when it's not run in the debugger), and as long as the debugger gets hung up on this particular error, it makes it practically impossible to debug anything *else*.

Comment: You can just tell your debugger to ignore the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't **handle** this exception, but avoid the situation were you pass an invalid handle!

**Edit:**
In debug mode, the code gives you a hint that something is wrong. So you should fix that error instead of handle the exception afterwords!

Comment: Since the debugger points to the error, i would simply debug this place. Watch the callstack and see why this is happening. If you're lucky it is a logical error... if it is a multithreading related problem, then: good luck

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem.

I checked for stack corruption, corruption of the handle etc. Eventually I discovered that I shouldn't have been calling `CloseHandle()`!

This was a handle returned by `FindFirstFile()`, the correct disposal function is `FindClose()`, not `CloseHandle()`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue, What worked for me was changing the debug architecture from x86 to x64.